# Equivalent of Oracle export for SQL Server and/or db2

Tags: sql-server, oracle, db2, export

Can SQL Server or db2 do entire database exports like oracle (using exp command)?

I've searched the internets and found bcp for SQL Server. But it seems I would have to iterate over all the tables to get what I want.

For db2 it looks to be roughly the same. Is there something I'm missing? Anyone have any suggestions and/or any opinions? Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for ***SQL SERVER***

**Backup & Restore**

To take an entire database with SQL Server, you can do a `BACKUP` and `RESTORE`

BACKUP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

RESTORE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

**Export and Import**

You can right click a database in SQL Server Management Studio, and under TASKS, click on EXPORT DATA. Follow the Wizard to choose the objects you want to export and put them into the appropriate location.

**Custom SSIS for Raw format**

Build a SSIS package that will read data from source table and put it into a RAW file on disk for later use. Raw files holds the structure of the table and the data.

Comment: Alright this works for sqlserver. However the backup file is saved locally on the database machine. I would be executing the command remotely with 'osql' and wanted the output of that command (mydatabase.bak) to be saved on the remote machine and not on the database machine. Is this possible? Or is this just something I will have to deal with?

Comment: As long as you use a UNC that the service account has full control over (the share and the folder), you should be able to backup and restore using TSQL (SSMS does not support UNC).

Comment: @Christopher Dancy - Just an FIY that exp in oracle has been phased out as of oracle 11g and replaced by the faster expdp utility. The expdp utility dumps the file to a server directory only or if the DBA has mapped network drives for oracle to read.

Answer (score 2):

DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows has a utility called db2move, which generates the DDL to rebuild the database from scratch, and iterates through all the tables to dump their contents to flatfiles via the EXPORT command.

Comment: Yea db2move does work but as you pointed out i will get the data from each table in its own file. I can work with it but was hoping to get something all in 1 file like oracles "exp" utility. Perhaps I was just being a bit greedy.

Comment: The only option to dump an entire DB2 database into one file is the BACKUP utility, but the resulting file is in a proprietary binary format that won't be of much use to you until you restore it back into DB2.